# Cocos2d-x 3.0 wp8 XAML GL program error

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

After enabling native debuging i am able to see where this is giving error. in CCGLProgram haveprogram function. It builds fine only while running on the device it gives this error. Also the shaders are precompiled for wp8 so I dont know why this problems exists.I am running it on my desktop and running on my nokia 820. The same works fine on my laptop on a simulator.

vshaderByteArray and fshaderbyteArray get a different value every time. I wanted to attach an image but it seems I need 50 reputation. So adding link below.

http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/wp8-xaml-version-3-2-gl-program-error/15679

Comment: don't use screenshots, you can copy/paste the relevant parts (log, callstack, code) as text in any good IDE just by selecting the window or text

Comment: I know, but I am on my mac partition now so couldnt. Also do you have to edit every cocos2d/cocos2d-x post out there. Just saying :).

Comment: my edits are mainly just tag updates